# when should I write custom methods in model vs model manager/ queryset

Tags: python, django, django-models

when should I write methods in the model itself and when in the model manager?

is it like all methods to get something should be written in manager and others in model

Comment: Not sure if there is a fixed case to choose one over other. I use model manager almost always.

Comment: it's kinda funny to use something when you don't know what its appropriate use is. there has to be something, I'm missing. I was watching a django con 2016 talk right now and the speaker said when you are working with an instance use model and when queryset use manager but I can't really digest it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a simple difference. Model methods act on a single instance. Manager methods create queries to act on multiple instances.

Comment: Er, yes. Why did you post that comment?

Comment: because if we can get queries from the model then why should one use manager